# Date format not applied when doing AddDay

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've got the following two queries:

```
    $startDate = (Get-Date -format s).AddDays(-6)
    $endDate = (Get-Date -format s)
    Write-Host $startDate
    Write-Host $endDate

    //Prints
    2015-05-02 16:23:52
    2015-05-08T16:47:56
```

I'd like to understand how to put the T back in the first printed dates. The space breaks my powershell script where I add that date to an LogParser.sql path:

```
Myquery.Sql?startdate='$startdate'+enddate='$enddate')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
$startDate = (Get-Date -format s).AddDays(-6)
```

throws an error (about `[system.string]` not having a function `AddDays`) for me with powershell 3.0.

I can get the output you want from this though:

```
"{0:s}" -f (Get-Date).AddDays(6)
```

Comment: I'm using powershell 2.0

Comment: Was that an indication that the `-f` version doesn't work for you?

Comment: It actually works! Is there a way to not have the T in there?

Comment: I'm confused? The whole point of this question was how to get the `T` back. You can probably manually format the date to avoid the `T` if you want. Look at the documentation on `-f` formatting of dates I.

Comment: What I actually wanted was the dates format to be consistent. My initial question was not asked with that in my mind, my bad. I'll check the documenration for -f, thanks.